# Call GET method by not using the <form> html tag

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am curious to know whether there is a way to call a GET method without having to use the `<form>` HTML tag. I just want a button that calls my `doGet()` servlet method when it is clicked. It is not worth creating an entire form if I will not send any data, I guess.
I was thinking of something like this: `<button method="get" action="MyServlet">`. Sorry, I am currently learning Java Web Development and HTML, so this question might sound stupid at first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several http verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH). But when you are talking about old-school web development, there are really only 2 (GET and POST). A form has the option to submit using GET or POST, but every time you type a URL into the address bar of your browser, you are actually making a GET request. That means that every time you click on a link you are making a GET request.

This is basically a long way of saying all you need to due is add:

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/to/whatever?q=ifyouneedtoaddquerystrings">Click On Me!!</a>
```

The kicker here is you can't add an data to the body of your request. But it doesn't seem like that is what you need.

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with appending some query parameters to that GET url?

Comment: No of course not. That is why they are there. BUT you need to make sure to encode anything you add. e.g. "me & my dog" should become "me%20%26%20my%20dog" because and ampersand and spaces are not valid in a URI. You can use `encodeURIComponent()` to accomplish this (if you have complete control over what the link will be then you can just make sure it will work. I was assuming it might be the result of user input)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I completely forgot about using URLs!

Answer (score 0):

Ther are two ways. First :-

```
<a href="UserController?id=MyString">Click Me</a>
```

and second :-

```
<img width="200" height="180" src="UserController?id=1234" id="id" alt="Image">
```

and corresponding servlet is:-

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String text=request.getParameter("id");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet UserController</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Value of text " +text+"</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> I just want a button that calls my doGet() servlet method when it is
>   clicked

Try this code:

```
<a href="MyServlet"><button>Call MyServlet</button></a>
```